# Is there a way to check the performance of a command in the console in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, benchmarking

I couldn't find any information on if this was possible but it would be useful I could call a method on a command in the `rails console` and determine the performance using any measurement but I was mostly thinking about in time.

For example, I'm trying to figure out which of these is faster:

```
[val2,val3,val4,val5,val6].find{|x| x != val1}
[val2,val3,val4,val5,val6].all?{|x| x == val1}
```

Is there something like this?

```
[val2,val3,val4,val5,val6].find{|x| x != val1}.performance
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is! And you don't even need Rails. Look into [benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) from the standard library.

As a sample:

```
require 'benchmark'

puts Benchmark.measure { [val2,val3,val4,val5,val6].find{|x| x != val1} }
puts Benchmark.measure { [val2,val3,val4,val5,val6].all?{|x| x == val1} }
```

The report that is output will show (in seconds):

- User CPU time.
- System CPU time.
- Sum of the User and System CPU times.
- The elapsed real time.

Something that looks like this:

```
0.350000   0.010000   0.360000 (  0.436450)
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this in the console?  I want to run ad-hoc type stuff not necessarily in the project code itself.

Comment: @persistence: yes, you can run that example code right from the console.

Comment: This is great for comparing methods via the console

Answer (score 2):

This gem:
https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```